# What Plagiarism level of master thesis is acceptable?

Tags: plagiarism

I am checking plagiarism of my master thesis.  It comes out 32 percent.  So upto what level of plagiarism is accepted?
My master thesis is on the topic of homomorphic encryption in Cloud and I uses turnitin online service for plagiarism checking.
Edit: I apologize that I do not included the detail that plagiarism level comes out 32 percent when I include my research paper as it is in my thesis. The paper are going to publish in IEEE conference. If I exclude this research paper, The plagiarism level is 12 percent.I also posted question related to it on academic stack exchange and if anyone interested, you can check the link
 [Can research paper information be used in thesis writing?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/72676/can-research-paper-information-be-used-in-thesis-writing/72683?noredirect=1#comment177374_72683)

Comment: None, if it's real plagiarism. If it refers to standard definitions (vector space) or references, this may indicate false positives. Anything else should be close to 0.

Comment: What do you mean "it comes out 32 percent?"

Comment: @CapeCode Presumably that some undefined automated check resulted in 32% copied text.

Comment: This cannot be answered without knowing the tool you were using, what this "32%" means, and what the conventions in your field are, but in the dark I would assume that you have a **big** problem if a third of your thesis are verbatim copies from existing sources.

Comment: @xLeirix I uses turnitin online service for plagiarism check.

Comment: The acceptable "plagiarism level" of any academic work is 0. Why would you need a software to test your own work? You *know* if you plagiarized or not... If you're question is "What is the maximum level of detectable plagiarism that will not get me expelled?" I think this website is not meant to give that kind of advice.

Comment: Rewrite everything in your own words and with proper citation and it will be zero. Don't play with it, it will hunt you in your career, it doesn't worth it.

Comment: vivek also asked about including his/her own research in his/her thesis
(http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/72676/can-research-paper-information-be-used-in-thesis-writing), perhaps "32%" is due to turnitin detecting his/her previously published research.

Comment: @user2768 Thanks for pointing out.  I have to ask them separate because of nature of both questions.

Comment: You wrote in [this comment](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/72676/can-research-paper-information-be-used-in-thesis-writing#comment177207_72676) that the overlap percent is 12 when you don't include your own published paper, and only goes up to 32 when you include it. That's very relevant information and you should include that in your post.

Comment: @ff524 Thanks for suggestions.  As it's a comment of different question, I don't want to mix these two questions to increase complexity.

Comment: You should include that detail here because it's very, very, very relevant to this question. See all the people saying that 32% seems very high ([this answer](http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/72681/11365), [this comment](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/72667/what-plagiarism-level-of-master-thesis-is-acceptable?noredirect=1#comment177229_72681))? They would think differently if they knew that it was 12% before you added your published paper. As a question-writer, you really need to give people *all* the information that they need in order to answer your question.

Answer (score 16):

The turnitin tool is saying that it thinks 32% of the text of your thesis could have been taken from other sources.

The software is a very blunt tool, and often has difficulty recognizing common turns of phrase and specialized terminology (e.g. I've seen "Without loss of generality we can assume that"  and "Traveling Salesman's Problem" flagged.)  It also doesn't recognize situations where there's a direct quote (properly delineated and cited) from another source.

Thus it's necessary for a human to review the report generated by the software to see what's going on.  Without seeing that report, no one can give you an authoritative answer to your question.  However, in my experience, I've never seen a paper with this high a score that didn't have significant problems.

To directly answer your question, no amount of plagiarism is acceptable in a master's thesis.

Comment: To add to your observations, when I sat on my department's academic misconduct committee, I had to reviewed the turn-it-in reports for all assignments in our department. I have also never seen a paper with a similarity index in excess of 30% that didn't have problems (although some did properly attributed the large block quotes and therefore did not plagiarize).

Comment: I have had a report over 30% that was basically fine. It was a fairly short assignment, and about 20% of the flagging was made up of tiny snippets.

Answer (score 3):

To answer a now-included question: there is no computer tool that can correctly identify all plagiarism. To decide whether you have plagiarised, you need to answer the question 'have I included text, images or ideas that are not my own without making that clear?'

Comment: Thanks for answering. According to our college norms, we have to generate the report and submit it with our master degree. The tool for generating report is Turnitin.

Comment: @vivek Something of that variety is pretty common. But it doesn't affect my answer. Turnitin is one tool that detects some plagiarism. It is not a redefinition of plagiarism.