# Can research paper information be used in thesis writing?

Tags: thesis

I am writing my master thesis.  Can I put my research paper data in this thesis?  The research paper had been accepted in IEEE conference.  Is it ethical to put research paper data as it is. As this is my work, so can I use it ?

Comment: Yes, but you must rewrite everything using different words and with new figures which have different styles and colors, in order not to be exact with the published version. All of this is to avoid self-plagiarism and some copyright issue of the journal if it is a different contract. This is the case in my faculty. However, I have seen some PhD thesis from reputable places with the papers just copied without any problem in the thesis, so your thesis advisor might know better.

Comment: @Mikey Thanks for answer.  The problem is by adding the content of my research paper the plagiarism level shots to 32 percent. When I remove that research paper the plagiarism level is just 12 percent.

Comment: @MikeyMike, I don't think there's a self-plagiarism problem here. vivek merely wants to include published research in a thesis. That's standard. (Rewriting everything using different words and styles sounds like plagiarism!)

Comment: @MikeyMike, with regards to copyright, it depends what copyright waiver was signed with IEEE. If IEEE permit redistribution via the author's webpage, then I think vivek can include the material without any concern.

Comment: In fact, you **must** use your research data in your thesis.

Answer (score 2):

There are two concerns here:

1. Does the publisher of your previously published work object to your reusing the material in your MS thesis?  This should be addressed in any copyright transfer agreement that you signed.  Most publishers are actually OK with students doing this but a few are not.
2. Does your institution allow students to reuse material from their published research papers in theses?  Some institutions have rules against this.

You'll need to check on both of these issues.

Comment: _Most publishers are actually OK with students doing this but a few are not._ — Standard practice suggests that the publishers that would object are loons.  Ignore them.

Comment: @Brian Thanks answering in both posts. Is IEEE permit reuse of paper?

Comment: See the discussion at https://www.ieee.org/publications_standards/publications/rights/permissions_faq.pdf

Comment: @vivek When submitting the final version to a conference, you (or maybe your co-author if you had one) probably have signed some agreement. Read it again if you're worried, but you shouldn't really be worried. Just ask your supervisor what you should do.

Comment: Sorry for late response. I checked the link provided by you and they are saying that you can use the paper in your thesis but proper referring must be provided to original author. Now If the paper is written by me, still I need to refer? Secondly, This paper is not published but only accepted till now, so can I refer this paper? Thanks